# Using relative references to reuse a macro for a control

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write an Excel 2007 macro for a coworker, but my VBA skills are pretty basic (pardon the pun). Essentially, what needs to happen is, when a checkbox is clicked, the neighboring cell to the right is filled with the username of the person logged in.

So far, here's the code I've come up with that allows me to do that:

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Range("J4").Activate
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18).Value = True Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Environ("UserName")
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Clear
    End If
End Sub
```

Just for the sake of reference, that "ActiveCell.Offset(0,18)" refers to a cell that is linked to the checkbox in question and contains its true/false value.

(EDIT: Also, the reason cell J4 is activated is because in this case, it's the cell containing the ActiveX checkbox)

That works perfectly, but that's not my problem. My problem is this: there are 49 more checkboxes in that row, and three more rows on this sheet, and 45 more sheets in this book. I do NOT want to have to copy paste the same code into a unique macro just to change the active cell. More importantly, as a good programmer, I shouldn't be repeating code like that. How should I write this so that I don't have to refer to a distinct cell every time?

EDIT 2: Holy smokes, Lance just helped me realize I was mistaken. The sheet uses form controls, not ActiveX controls. Greatly sorry, everyone.

Comment: Are you using ActiveX checkboxes or Form Control checkboxes?

Comment: ActiveX checkboxes. Also I should note, the reason I activated cell J4 is because that was the cell that contains the ActiveX checkbox

Comment: To do what you want you either need to use Form Controls, or create a Class Module for your ActiveX checkboxes.  See here for an example with ActiveX command buttons: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/219122-application-caller-command-buttons-sheet.html

Comment: Woops, I screwed up. They ARE form controls after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is easy to do with a Sheet object, it's pretty hard to do with an ActiveX Control object. You can't self-reference the name of an ActiveX Control in its event, unless it's passed to it, and you also can't reference the name of the event subroutine to extract the name, and you can't reference the name of the routine that called a routine.

I also attempted to trigger off of the Worksheet Change and SelectionChange events, but those don't trigger off of a checkbox change, even if it has a LinkedCell that changes

What I finally came up with was the somewhat generic wrapper for the click event, that you'll have to modify the string to match the Checkbox name:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

  NameCopy Me, "CheckBox1"

End Sub
```

and then a Namecopy function that sets the cell -7 to the left of the LinkedCell to the name value.

```
Public Sub NameCopy(wsheet As Worksheet, cname As String)

If wsheet.OLEObjects(cname).Object.Value = True Then
    Range(wsheet.OLEObjects(cname).LinkedCell).Offset(0, -7).Value = Environ("UserName")
End If

End Sub
```

It's easier with a Forms checkbox, you can use this Macro for all your checkboxes. Just remember to set the Macro to this:

```
Public Sub NameCopy()

Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)

If shp.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
  ActiveSheet.Range(shp.ControlFormat.LinkedCell).Offset(0, -7).Value = Environ("UserName")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually this is a better option, BUT: you can't update all checkboxes at once because it will use the same UserName for all checked cells - you still need to send one box at the time NameCopy(ByRef chk As **MSForms.CheckBox**) and it will know the offset. Also you need to properly reference the range: **chk.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1)**, and remove the name when unchecked

Comment: Thank you two so much for your help! Lance, I tried your code, but it's giving me an error: "Invalid use of Me keyword". Any thoughts?

Comment: Me gives a quick reference to the sheet that the Checkbox is on, but you can just use ActiveSheet probably. Oh, I do see one error where I left out the variable type in the sub parameter. Edited in now.

Comment: Thanks! I made the changes, and it runs now, but nothing is happening. I'd like to walk through the macro, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on one of the first lines, then use F8 to walk through.  My bet would be on the references of what the LinkedCell value is and the Offset used. I made it specifically based on setting the Linked Cell to the J4 reference, i.e. on the cell it was in.

Comment: Uh, I just realized that this won't completely work the way you want it to, since it sets all the true checkboxes to the same name. I'll have to look into that.

Comment: Yeah, I think I see what you mean. It gets the for each loop and just skips straight to the end. Almost like it's not recognizing the checkbox as an object... Not sure what to make of it

Comment: Hmmm, maybe instead of an ActiveX checkbox, you made a Forms checkbox.

Comment: I admit, I don't know whether they're ActiveX or Forms. The checkboxes were already there when I was asked to write the macro. When you asked me which they were, I created two new checkboxes, one of each kind, and compared them visually to the ones that were there, and ActiveX looked most similar. A Band-Aid solution, I know, but I don't know of any other way to tell.

As long as I'm giving full disclosure, the reason the controls are linked to other cells is because those linked cells are used in some kind of formula that determines the color of the corresponding row. It's not a macro, so I'm

Comment: not exactly sure how he did it, but when you click the first check box, for example, the row turns blue. Clicking a checkbox that says "complete" turns it green, etc.

Comment: Instead of looking at their appearance, look at their properties. They will have different properties. You may have condition formatting set on the rows that keys to the LinkedCells, which would be easy to modify.

Comment: Ok, found one more limitation in VBA, so you can't be completely generic on the wrapper. It works now for ActiveX checkboxes, and I've changed the reference to be -7 from your current LinkedCell, hopefully that is consistent.

Comment: Oh boy, big mistake made by me. They ARE form controls. Sorry everyone. I've edited the OP to reflect this little screwup.

Comment: Unfortunately it still didn't work for me :/ @tigeravatar's response worked though, so I've accepted his answer. Thank you so much for all of your help (and patience) Lance!

Comment: Hold up, it DID work, I just missed it because the offset put it in a cell where I didn't expect to see it. As a result, I have marked your answer instead because you were here since the beginning. Thanks so much Lance!!!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using form controls, this is really easy.  You can use `Application.Caller` to have the code access the clicked checkbox, and then use it's `TopLeftCell` property to get where the checkbox is located, and then you can perform whatever operation you want.  In your case, something like this I'm guessing:

```
Sub Checkbox_Click()

    With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
        If .Value = 1 Then  'Checkbox is checked
            .TopLeftCell.Offset(, 1).Value = Environ("UserName")
        Else
            .TopLeftCell.Offset(, 1).ClearContents
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @tigeravatar You are an absolute legend. People pay for this kind of help; completely saved my skin. I can copy paste the check-box and it relative references the cell it's on. This is so good, thank you.